# Why do WordPress templates like single.php loop over while (have_posts())?

Tags: wordpress

In the Twenty Fourteen theme and many others authored by experts, single.php contains the code:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
endwhile;
```

Is this any different or better than

```
the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
```

Is there a scenario where WordPress may expect single.php to be able to display more or less than exactly one post or is there another reason authors choose to use a while loop?

Answer (score 0):

the `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` is there by default so you can put conditional logic like in the example code below and won't get a 404 just incase there's no post or the permalink changes.

```
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope it helps.